# CSS3 keyframes breaks in safari

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I have this code for a loading spinner, it works in all browsers, except safari, where it breaks the entire site, I've narrowed it down to the issue being the webkit specific code below but can't figure out why it brakes, any ideas:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin{ 0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }; }

@-webkit-keyframes spinoff{ 0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); }; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have unnecessary semicolons after the `100%` definition in your code. Apparently Safari chokes on it while the others ignore it.

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin{ 
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinoff{ 
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } 
}
```